# javascript array empty using .push .text

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having an issue with the code that I was given as an example from a previous SO question - it is working about 95% but the order array is appearing empty why?

**HTML:**

```
<input class="order" value="<?php echo $order; ?>" type="text"  />
```

**JS:**

```
$('body').on("click", "#brands_by_category_submit_btn", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();               
        var self       = $(this);
        var order      =  []; 
        var id         = $("#manID").data("id");
        var brand_name = $("#brand_name").data("id");
        var data       = grabData(true);

        $(".order").each(function(){
            order.push($(this).text());
        })

        if(data.length)
        {
            var data_array = { 
                id : id,
                brand_name : brand_name, 
                cat_id     : data,
                order      : order, 
                state      : 1
            };
```

Comment: Psst: `var order = $(".order").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text()` returns the text content of a node, like `<p>this text here</p>`. An `<input />` element doesn't have text content, so `$('input').text()` will just return an empty string. Your `order` array should be an array of empty strings then. Maybe you want to extract the values?

```
$(".order").each(function(){
            order.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
order.push($(this).val());
```